# How do I format warnings captured with logging.captureWarnings?

Tags: python, logging, warnings

I have used the following code to get warnings to be logged:

```
import logging
logging.captureWarnings(True)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s')
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

This works, however, my logging formatter is not applied, and the warnings come out looking like this:

```
WARNING:py.warnings:/home/joakim/.virtualenvs/masterload/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py:100: Warning: 
InnoDB: ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC requires innodb_file_per_table.
```

instead of the expected format:

```
2012-11-12 18:19:44,421 INFO    START updating products
```

How can I apply my normal formatting to captured warning messages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You created a handler, but never configured the logging module to use it:

```
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

You need to add this handler to a logger; the root logger for example:

```
logging.getLogger().addHandler(console_handler)
```

Alternatively, you can add the handler to the warnings logger only; the [`captureWarnings()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings) states that it uses `py.warnings` for captured warnings:

```
logging.getLogger('py.warnings').addHandler(console_handler)
```

Instead of creating a handler and formatter explicitly, you can also just call [`basicConfig()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) to configure the root logger:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

The above basic configuration is the moral equivalent of the handler configuration you set up.

Answer (score 7):

[`logging.captureWarnings`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#integration-with-the-warnings-module) logs to a logger named `py.warnings`, so you need to add your handler to that logger:

```
import logging

logging.captureWarnings(True)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s')
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
py_warnings_logger = logging.getLogger('py.warnings')
py_warnings_logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#integration-with-the-warnings-module) says that *If capture is True, warnings issued by the warnings module will be redirected to the logging system. Specifically, a warning will be formatted using warnings.formatwarning() and the resulting string logged to a logger named 'py.warnings' with a severity of WARNING.*

Therefore I would try to

```
# get the 'py.warnings' logger
log = logging.getLogger('py.warnings')
# assign the handler to it
log.addHandler(console_handler)
```